# Silverlight - Audio - Loopback

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, microphone

How to avoid LoopBack of audio in Silverlight?

I am using silverlight to capture audio and stream it. This works fine when using a headset as a microphone, but when I use the built in microphone and the speaker of the laptop, it loops back and I get an echo.

Any idea on how can I avoid that? And is there any built in classes in Silverlight for Acoustic Noise Cancellation as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an audiophile but I dont think you can completely avoid that loopback as it is hardware related. You can however try a combination of these:

-Use a DSP library in your silverlight app to filter out the noise

-Detect the loopback and reduce the gain of the mic or the volume of the speakers

-Ask the user would to adjust the mic gain and/or speaker volume

-The user would need to place the mic in a different position

-Use a mic that is built to cancel out loopback (noise cancelling)

Even big products like skype cant handle loopback gracefully so they advice the user to use a headphone instead of builtin mic/speakers. but most modern laptops already come with the mic in such a setting as not to cause loopback or echo